# PHP Report Generation in PDF format

Tags: php

I intend to generate PDF reports using PHP. Does my 3rd party server require to have any special feature for this action to take place?. Your feedbacks are kindly appreciated.

Comment: Depends on your server, your settings, and what you're using to generate the plugins.  The cool thing about SO is that *after* you try it and *if* you receive issues, **then** you can post questions for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of how you want to generate your PDF.

By example [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) is a `PHP` library which will not require any special feature on your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate it as PHP you don’t need anything special just **DOMPDF** from GitHub witch I recommend, here is the link.

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

It will print any HTML as PDF so it’s really easy to use, I have an example which includes a form witch you can use to input as HTML and it will make a nice PDF for you.

http://lab.medanny.com/pdf/dompdf/www/simple.php

Here is the Code:

```html
<?php
require_once "../dompdf_config.inc.php";
if(isset($_POST['html'])){

$html =$_POST['html'];

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("download.pdf");

}

?>


<FORM ACTION="" METHOD=POST>

HTML:<BR>
<TEXTAREA NAME="html" COLS=40 ROWS=6></TEXTAREA>

<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="submit">
</FORM>
```